# Is there a way to create a link in a datasheet view in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We're using Sharepoint to track/control our customer onboarding process.  Basically there are items which list each deliverable and it's due date, and the different groups need to check that list daily and make sure their tasks are done and update the item.

Previously we created a datasheet view, which makes it easy to see just our tasks and update them.  Unfortunately there's another item we need to see in order to complete our task.  In a standard view we can show a link to that second item, but it doesn't look like you can do so in a datasheet view... which leaves us with opening up both views and going back and forth to do the setups.

Is there some way that we could get that link into the datasheet view?

EDIT: Apparently I made a mistake in the question.  The field in question is a lookup field to another item in sharepoint.  In standard view it links to the other item just fine, but in datasheet view it just comes across as text.  Is there a way to get the Lookup field to show up as a link in Datasheet view?

Comment: Could you please clear that up? do you need to add a single link on the datasheet view page? A link on every item (calculated)? or a link for every group?

Comment: A link on every item, it's actually a lookup to a setup form we use when creating the client in our system.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it does seem you cannot use a lookup field on a calculated fields, and Excel view doesn't allow opening a lookup item - it opens a combo with all lookup items, but doesn't open the item. However, there are some options that seem to work here as well. Lets assume your table, Tasks, has a lookup fields to another table, Clients.

1. A good option if Clients only has very few columns - Add a calculated column to Clients with all data, and use it for the lookup. For example, if clients has the columns `Name` and `Phone`, create another column that shows both: `=[Name] & ", " & [Phone]`, so you can see all data in excel view (that way you don't need a link).
2. Add another integer field to Tasks, that has just the ID of the Client, and add a calculated field to Tasks with the formula `="http://yourserver/lists/clients/DispForm.aspx?ID=" & [ClientID]` . This will create a URL string that would work on Excel view. So, you'll have to fill the ClientID (which isn't too comfortable, I admit), or use JavaScript to fill this column automatically when a lookup is chosen (I've done something similar, in fact).
3. As Auguste suggested, use a Link instead of a lookup. Again. this is less comfortable than a lookup, but the easiest option here.

Comment: There are too many fields for option 1, and option 3 would depend on our Client Services team being able to put together a valid link... so I think we're stuck with #2.  Unfortunately there does not appear to be an ID column in the list for the form we're trying to link to... Any ideas how to get that?

Comment: There's an ID for every Share Point item. You can create a view to see them, or look for them on the address bar (e.g. http://.../clients/DispForm.aspx?ID=4)

Answer (score 0):

I have no trouble doing so in Datasheet View.  Any link or email address I insert into a Single Line of Text column becomes a link in both Standard and Datasheet view.

Comment: The field in question is a Lookup field, I probably should have been more clear in my original question.  (Actually I suck at sharepoint and didn't realize the difference...)

Comment: Telos, it's OK for you to edit your question to add clarifications like this so they don't get buried in comments.

Comment: I will be unable to help you further until I return to work in two weeks, I'm afraid.  I do not have WSS running at home.  Perhaps somebody else can better help you than I.